# How to prepare an RDD for multiple joins against it without repeated shuffles?

Tags: apache-spark

I have some Spark code which is roughly as follows:

```
val source : RDD[(K, V)] = ???

val tW : RDD[(K, W)] = ???
source.cogroup(tW).doStuff()

// tX depends on result of previous cogropup
val tX : RDD[(K, X)] = ??? 
source.cogroup(tX).doStuff()

// tY depends on result of previous cogropup
val tY : RDD[(K, Y)] = ???
source.cogroup(tY).doStuff()

// tZ depends on result of previous cogropup
val tZ : RDD[(K, Z)] = ???
source.cogroup(tZ).doStuff()
```

This is a bit of a simplification.  I've omitted the details of the chain of dependences.  I've also omitted that the driver is forcing evaluation of the output of the cogroup after each step (so Spark is not able to be lazy and wait until all my RDDs are defined).

The `cogroup` operations require the left and right hand inputs be partitioned appropriately, and what I'm finding is that the `source` RDD is being repeatedly shuffled, but I presume in exactly the same way each time.

What can I do in Spark to shuffle `source` just once and cache/persist it in a way which will allow multiple `cogroup` operations against it without incurring repeated shuffles?

Comment: Without testing this out myself, I would try getting the partitioner used for the first cogroup and passing it into the following ones. This should hint that the partition is the same. There is the possibility that you will have to override RDD itself and create a customer partitioner, but I'd try just re-using at first.